# Bounding variables $X$ and $X + 1$ using Markov's inequality

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Suppose $X \sim \text{Geometric}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ where $X$ is the number of failures. Then let $Y = X + 1$ (i.e., $Y$ counts the number of trials). Then we have,

$$E(X) = \frac{1}{p} - 1 = 2 - 1 = 1$$

$$E(Y) = \frac{1}{p} = 2$$

Suppose we want to find a bound on $P(X \ge 9)$. By Markov's inequality, we have,

$$P(X \ge 9) \le \frac{E(X)}{9} = \frac{1}{9}$$

Moreover, substituting for $Y$ now, we also have,

$$P(X \ge 9) = P(Y - 1 \ge 9) = P(Y \ge 10) \le \frac{E(Y)}{10} = \frac{2}{10}$$

Is it expected that these two bounds are different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is expected. However, summing a positive constant to the random variable will make the upper bound worse.

Markov's inequality states that if $X$ is a non-negative random variable, then, $$P(X \ge a) \le \frac{E(X)}{a} $$ for any $a>0$. Let $a > E(X)$ otherwise the bound is useless. Then, for $b \ge 0$, we have
$$
  P(X+b \ge a + b) \le  \frac{E(X+b)}{a+b} = 1 - \frac{a - E(X)}{a+b},
$$
which monotonically increases with $b$. Thus, the best we can do is $b=0$.

---

On the other hand, it is interesting to note that if $\mathrm{supp}(X) \subset [x_0, \infty)$, $x_0>0$, then we should choose $b = -x_0$ to improve the bound.